# When should you use django-admin.py versus manage.py?

Tags: django, django-admin

Background:

When I run the `django-admin.py loaddata example.json` I get this error. "ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined." I understand the problem. It needs the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to be able to access the database to do this import. I've had this problem before and I've managed to side step it thus far.

In reading the docs, I discovered that the `manage.py` is a wrapper for django-admin.py; it puts the project on the `sys.path` and sets the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment. Woot! Whoa! I know how to fix my problem.

Soo...
Why do the Django [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/django-admin/) code examples use django-admin.py instead of manage.py when demonstrating subcommands such as `loaddata` and `dumpdata`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable is set, you can use `django-admin.py` from any working directory, whereas you need to be in the project directory to use `./manage.py` (or have it in your path).

Use `virtualenv`, and have `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` set by `bin/activate`, and then you can use `django-admin.py`.

Answer (score 9):

> Why do the Django documentation code examples using django-admin.py instead of manage.py when demonstrating subcommands such as loaddata and dumpdata?

Well, because these scripts are the same in priciple, with the differences, you already mentioned. The Django docs also mention

```
django-admin.py <subcommand> [options]
manage.py <subcommand> [options]
```

side by side. Usually you use `django-admin.py` to start a new project or application and `manage.py` to do the rest.

Comment: I do think this makes the documentation more confusing for less experienced users and I've got about 9 months working with django. Thanks for your help!