# Django settings not configured error

Tags: python, django

I am doing the Django introductory tutorial from here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial05/

As described there, I opened the python shell and tried to import the project, like this:

```
from polls.models import Question
```

However, I get this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I don't understand the error message very well. Where exactly should I define `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` or call `settings.configure()` ?

If I try to open the django shell, I get the same message.

Comment: try `python manage.py shell`

Comment: @dnit13 yeah, but do you see the tutorial or anywhere in the 1.9 docs mentioning the `python manage.py shell` as opposed to `django-admin shell`?..thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I don't see it being opposed, but being mentioned here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/#playing-with-the-api

Comment: @dnit13 yeah, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run `python manage.py shell` from the root of your project - it automatically sets the environment variable pointing to your project settings.

Or, open the [*Django shell*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-shell) via `django-admin` setting the environment variable beforehand:

```
$ export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="myproj.settings"
$ django-admin shell  # requires the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to be set
```

Also see:

- [When should you use django-admin.py verus manage.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220303/when-should-you-use-django-admin-py-verus-manage-py)